# Split data into equal chunks. The last entry of 1st chunk shouldn't match the first entry of next

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a dataset of IDs which have mutliple entries of data. I want to split this dataset into chunks of a fixed size. But I need all data entries pertaining to an ID to be in the same chunk.

I tried ordering by IDs and assigning an index to every row and dividing it into chunks. But I can't figure out how to keep all the entries with the same ID in the same chunk.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how to keep all the entries with the same ID in the same chunk.

Here I took sample dataframe to Split it into a separate chunk
[image]

To separate it in different chunks with same Id I wrote a code where I am storing the occurrence of each Id in an ascending order and then looping over it to with respect to occurrence and it is splitting dataframe into smaller chunks with similar ids

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

lm = demo_df.groupBy("Id").count().orderBy(col("Id"))
count_list = lm.rdd.map(lambda x: x[1]).collect()

per_df = demo_df

for i in count_list:
    cur_df = per_df.orderBy(col("Id")).limit(i)
    per_df = per_df.subtract(cur_df)
    cur_df.show(truncate=False)
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]